# Installing drivers in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers

I just installed Ubuntu 10.4LTS on my machine and I'm having trouble following the driver install directions. I am told to execute this command in the 'linux source tree':

```
make include/linux/version.h.
```

How do I get to this source tree from a terminal?

Comment: Please post what exact drivers you want to install...

Comment: And a link to said directions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't! You need to install the Linux headers (if I recall correctly, the package is linux-headers-generic). The file you are looking for is there. That `make` command is needed if you build the kernel from source and is not already installed on your system.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to install a driver, it probably has a package somewhere that you need to install. However you didn't mention what the driver is, so I can't help you much further.

Anyway, I would like to point out that Linux usually comes with the drivers you need already, and Ubuntu especially so (except some closed source drivers that it will ask you to install if need be).